# Web Simulator For Native iOS app

Tags: android, ios, android-emulator, ios-simulator

I need to showcase the native iOS apps I have developed, on my Website. I don't want to just display the screenshots, but I want the users to interact with the app as if they are viewing it on their iOS device. Is there a simulator available to do the same? It will be helpful if anyone can guide me to write one myself, in case none is available. Even if one is available for android, it may help to know the architecture.

NOTE : I am talking about native apps, not the webapps

Comment: Native iOS app as in it's an IPA that you submit to Apple to be put in the App Store?

Comment: Yes, but instead i want to use the .ipa file in a web simulator or something like that.

Comment: Go to https://app.io/ and follow the instructions. There are options for uploading the .ipa and having the app running on the web as in a simulator.